# Checking if user input is an integer in c#

Tags: c#

So I'm making a little text game, and I need the user to enter an integer when it asks for grid size. And if an integer isn't entered I want the question to be asked again.

Right now I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Grid Size.");
int gridSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I need a way to check if the input is a integer, and then ask again if it's not. Thanks

Comment: check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
int gridSize;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Grid Size.");
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out gridSize))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That was invalid. Enter a valid Grid Size.");
}

// use gridSize here
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var input = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
{
}
```